# Winform Merging two columns

Tags: winforms, datagridview, merge

HI, 
I want to create a datagridview in a form with 4 columns basically which has only 2 column headers, ie i want to merge only the column headers of 2 columns.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

pls, check if code from this SO question [winform - merging datagridview headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934317/winform-merging-datagridview-headers/1937719#1937719) and its answers would work for you

Answer (score 0):

i assume you're binding to a sql-provided datatable, right? If so, why not combine the results in your datatable and bind that. Simpler, with less programming.

E.g.

```
SELECT col1 + ' ' + col2, col3 + ' ' + col4 FROM someTable ORDER BY col1 + ' ' + col2
```

Fancier version:

```
SELECT col1 + ' ' + col2 AS 'Fancy Column Name 1' , 
col3 + ' ' + col4 AS 'Fancy Column Name 2 
FROM someTable ORDER BY col1 + ' ' + col2
```