# Merge Edit and Delete columns in one Column in Windows Forms using VS2010 , C# Code

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

[image]I have one Edit column and another Delete column in a Windows DataGridView which I am binding programatically .. Say I have one column " Edit " and another " Delete " ,  which both are bound to "ID" .. Now I want to merge these both columns as " Edit/Delete" where there will be Links for " Edit " and "Delete " .. but as per VS Studio 2010's TableLayoutPanel  property of C# windows forms property , I can not have two controls in one Cell .. How to achieve this scenario using C# Windows Forms code

Code :-

```
public frmTopicSectionManagement()

{

InitializeComponent();

PopulateTopicList();

PopulateGridView();

}

private void PopulateGridView()

{

try

{

string PYear = "";

int pId;

int TopicId = Convert.ToInt32(((Topiclist)cmbTopics.SelectedItem).TopicId);

PYear = StartUp.PlanYear.ToString();

pId = StartUp.ProductTypId;

TopicSectionLookup objTopicSection = new TopicSectionLookup();

if (repo.GetAllTopicSections() != null && TopicId == -1 && PYear != "")


  {

 GridView_TopicSection.DataSource = repo.GetAllTopicSectionDisplayTopicTitle(pId, PYear).ToList();                    GridView_TopicSection.Columns["ProductType"].Visible = false;

 GridView_TopicSection.Columns["Year"].Visible = false;                 
PopulateAllGridView();

        }
    else if (repo.GetAllTopicSections() != null)
    {
    GridView_TopicSection.DataSource = repo.GetAllTopicsForSectionManagement(TopicId, pId, PYear).ToList();
                GridView_TopicSection.Columns["ProductType"].Visible = false;
                GridView_TopicSection.Columns["Year"].Visible = false;
                PopulateAllGridView();
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
              }

    private void PopulateAllGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            //Add Update Button to DataGridView(Problems here)
            if (!GridView_TopicSection.Columns.Contains("Update") || !!GridView_TopicSection.Columns.Contains("Delete"))
            {
                DataGridViewLinkColumn updateColumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
                updateColumn.Name = "Edit";
                updateColumn.HeaderText = "Update";
                updateColumn.Text = "Edit";
                updateColumn.Width = 50;
                updateColumn.DividerWidth = 0;
                updateColumn.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                GridView_TopicSection.Columns.Add(updateColumn);

                //  Add Delete Button to GridView (and here)
                DataGridViewLinkColumn deletecolumn = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
                deletecolumn.Name = "Delete";
                deletecolumn.HeaderText = "Delete";
                deletecolumn.Text = "Delete";
                deletecolumn.Width = 103;
                deletecolumn.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
                GridView_TopicSection.Columns.Add(deletecolumn);
            }

            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["TopicId"].Visible = false;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["TopicSectionLookupId"].Visible = false;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["TopicTitle"].Visible = true;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["TopicTitle"].Width = 200;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["SectionText"].Visible = true;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["SectionText"].Width = 200;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["Year"].Visible = false;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["ProductTypeId"].Visible = false;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["IsActive"].Visible = true;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["IsActive"].Width = 80;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["IsBenifit"].Visible = true;
            GridView_TopicSection.Columns["IsBenifit"].Width = 80;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did not get this - "but as per VS Studio 2010's TableLayoutPanel property of C# windows forms property , I can have two controls in one Cell"

Comment: Is my understanding correct [the problem statement what you have mentioned] ?

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming* that you want to have **two links** in a Single Cell named **Edit / Delete**, then I think you should  should create a custom column type with a custom cell type that contains two LinkLabels.

More [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdesigner/thread/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/) on multiple controls in a single datagrid view cell [with source code].

**[Solution 1 - *Merged* Header]**

You need not merge the columns, rather merge the headers -  like [this](http://i.imagehost.org/0196/s3.gif). And then, please refer the solution in [the related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1937719/763026). This should solve your issue.

**[Solution 2 - *Merged* Column]**
You can host multiple controls in a single data grid view cell and that is what you want to achieve. Create a winforms **user control with two link labels** and host that user control in the datagridview cell. So you will have Edit/Delete in a single cell *[what you are referring as merged column*]. See here for hosting custom controls in a datagrid view cell - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx?PHPSESSID=o1fb21liejulfgrptbmi9dec92

Comment: By your screenshot I can make out - either it has to be a SingleHeader or a cell with multiple controls i.e. two link labels in your case [which you are confused by the nomenclature of "merged columns"]. We have already discussed this & **I have provided both the approaches in the answer already with source code.** You have to now use the approaches and work out the code which suits your requirement.